# Why Tomcat reports severe error and not working after using Intellij downloaded struts?

Tags: intellij-idea, struts2

I followed the doc:https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-to-use-struts-2.html

Step 1. New Project

Step 2. Finish and fix problem in project stucture panel

Step 3. Run 'Tomcat'

Step 4. Get error

Some details:
Tomcat 8.5.14 / Struts 2 2.5.13(auto-download)
[image]

Server Log Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2017-11-22 02:52:46,624] Artifact HelloStruts:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 13 2017 12:55:45 UTC
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.14.0
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\dram2\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_14_HelloStruts
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\dram2\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_14_HelloStruts\conf\logging.properties
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\dram2\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_14_HelloStruts
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\temp
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 1.5.2.
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
22-Nov-2017 14:52:47.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.183 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.278 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.302 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.305 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.307 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.308 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1186 ms
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.355 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.367 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
22-Nov-2017 14:52:48.371 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 63 ms
Connected to server
[2017-11-22 02:52:48,749] Artifact HelloStruts:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22-Nov-2017 14:52:49.400 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22-Nov-2017 14:52:49.424 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22-Nov-2017 14:52:49.424 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-11-22 02:52:49,437] Artifact HelloStruts:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
22-Nov-2017 14:52:58.363 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\webapps\manager
22-Nov-2017 14:52:58.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\webapps\manager has finished in 50 ms
```

These lines might be important:

```
22-Nov-2017 14:52:49.400 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22-Nov-2017 14:52:49.424 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22-Nov-2017 14:52:49.424 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-11-22 02:52:49,437] Artifact HelloStruts:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Tomcat Localhost Log

```
24-Nov-2017 10:40:21.993 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter struts2
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Project Structure - Modules
[image]

Project Structure - Facets
[image]

And Artifacts
[image]

Which might be important is that, I fix a problem showed in 'Project Structue - Problem' panel, but it still cannot run.

The tomcat cannot working and I cannot access 'http://localhost:8080/index.jsp'.
But if I new a project without struts 2, tomcat is working.

If there's any other info should I provide, please let me know by comments.
How can I fix it, any advice would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Do you have any additional information in other log tabs in run tool window?

Comment: Please, see server log for details.

Comment: I added 'Tomcat Localhost Log' above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to solve it is not direct but simple enough.

**Just download the struts 2 on its website.
Choose 'Use library' when newing a project.
Everything works right.**

I still don't know why IntelliJ downloaded struts 2 cannot work, but at least I can do my stuff on.

Here is step by step [Segment Fault](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000012118006)